# How to use Alamofire 4 SessionManager?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swift3

I was using Alamofire 3.4 in Swift 2.3 and I need to update my code to Swift 3 and Alamofire 4.
I was using Alamofire's Manager to do a POST in a url. I read the documentation about SessionManager and I understand that the request uses the method .GET.

I was using Manager .Response() to get the callback from the request, now that's changed in SessionManager.

How do I make a POST method using SessionManager? And how do I get the response from the request?

This is my original code:

```
import UIKit
import AEXML
import Alamofire

class Request: NSObject {

    internal typealias RequestCompletion = (statusCode: Int?, error:NSError?) -> ()
    private var completionBlock: RequestCompletion!

    var serverTrustPolicy: ServerTrustPolicy!
    var serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy]!
    var afManager: Manager!

    func buildBdRequest(ip : String, serviceStr : String, completionBlock:RequestCompletion){
       let url = getURL(ip, service: serviceStr)
        configureAlamoFireSSLPinningWithCertificateData()
        makeAlamofireRequest(url)

        self.completionBlock = completionBlock
    }

    func makeAlamofireRequest(url : String){
        self.afManager.request(.POST, url)
            .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
            .response { request, response, data, error in

                print("data - > \n    \(data.debugDescription) \n")
                print("response - >\n    \(response.debugDescription) \n")
                print("error - > \n    \(error.debugDescription) \n")

                var statusCode = 0

                if response != nil {
                    statusCode = (response?.statusCode)!
                }
                   self.completionBlock(statusCode: statusCode, error: error)
        }

    }


    private func getURL(ip : String, service: String) -> String{
        return ip + service;
    }

    func configureAlamoFireSSLPinningWithCertificateData() {
        self.serverTrustPolicies = [ :
            //            "github.com": self.serverTrustPolicy!
        ]

        self.afManager = Manager(
            configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @yasin, any updates here?

Comment: @MuruganandhamK no, nothing yet. I reversed my code to continue to use swift 2.3 and Alamofire 3.5

Comment: please update here. Once u got anything.

Comment: Same issue here

Comment: @MuruganandhamK
You can check my answer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've migrated your code to Swift 3 and Alamofire 4 and here it's a result :

```
internal typealias RequestCompletion = (Int?, Error?) -> ()?
private var completionBlock: RequestCompletion!
var afManager : SessionManager!


func makeAlamofireRequest(url :String){
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default

    afManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
    afManager.request(url, method: .post).validate().responseJSON {
                response in
                switch (response.result) {
                case .success:
                    print("data - > \n    \(response.data?.debugDescription) \n")
                    print("response - >\n    \(response.response?.debugDescription) \n")
                    var statusCode = 0
                    if let unwrappedResponse = response.response {
                        let statusCode = unwrappedResponse.statusCode
                    }
                    self.completionBlock(statusCode, nil)

                    break
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("error - > \n    \(error.localizedDescription) \n")
                    let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode
                    self.completionBlock?(statusCode, error)
                    break
                }
            }
}
```

Some notes about code:

In Alamofire 4.0 you don't need to manually validate between codes 200..300. `validate()` method do it automatically.

[Documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#automatic-validation) :

> Automatically validates status code within 200...299 range, and that the Content-Type header of the response matches the Accept header of the request if one is provided.

You can use `response` parameter in `responseJSON` method. It contains all information that you need in your code.

About `request` method

`open func request(_ url: URLConvertible, method: HTTPMethod = .get, parameters: Parameters? = nil, encoding: ParameterEncoding = URLEncoding.default, headers: HTTPHeaders? = nil) -> DataRequest`

All parameters except URL, are initially nil or has a default value. So it's no problem to add parameters or headers to your request.

Hope it helps you

Comment: Do you have to re-instantiate the session manager before each request or can you share the same instance between multiple requests?

Comment: @cbbcloud You can create one SessionManager and share the same instance  in multiple requests.

Comment: @kamwysoc very good JOB. can you tell me why `.validate().` used ?

Comment: @Jack please read documentation https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/0456f5b501f46591a77b4bb6f2e2e2a97d095042/Documentation/Usage.md#automatic-validation

Comment: (old) SessionManager > (new)  Session